# Including paths with rpcgen

Tags: c, multithreading, makefile, rpc

Pretty simple doubt: I'm using `rpcgen` for implementing a RPC server that applies mathematical functions in a vector and returns it to the client. Therefore I need to use `<math.h>`. But since I'm compiling the project through `make` using a makefile instead of using `gcc` or `g++`, I get confused on how exactly I should do that. When simply including the file in `rpc_server.c` and using the `log(x)` function I get:

```
cc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG    -c -o rpc_xdr.o rpc_xdr.c
cc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG     -o rpc_client  rpc_clnt.o rpc_client.o rpc_xdr.o -lnsl 
cc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG    -c -o rpc_svc.o rpc_svc.c
cc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG    -c -o rpc_server.o rpc_server.c
cc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG     -o rpc_server  rpc_svc.o rpc_server.o rpc_xdr.o -lnsl
rpc_server.o: In function `ln_4_svc':
/home/gfrebello/Desktop/Sistemas Distribuídos/RPC/rpc_server.c:27: undefined reference to `log'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:42: recipe for target 'rpc_server' failed
make: *** [rpc_server] Error 1
```

Here's my makefile:

```
# This is a template Makefile generated by rpcgen

# Parameters

CLIENT = rpc_client
SERVER = rpc_server

SOURCES_CLNT.c = 
SOURCES_CLNT.h = 
SOURCES_SVC.c = 
SOURCES_SVC.h = 
SOURCES.x = rpc.x

TARGETS_SVC.c = rpc_svc.c rpc_server.c rpc_xdr.c 
TARGETS_CLNT.c = rpc_clnt.c rpc_client.c rpc_xdr.c 
TARGETS = rpc.h rpc_xdr.c rpc_clnt.c rpc_svc.c rpc_client.c rpc_server.c

OBJECTS_CLNT = $(SOURCES_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o)
OBJECTS_SVC = $(SOURCES_SVC.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_SVC.c:%.c=%.o)
# Compiler flags 

CFLAGS += -g -DRPC_SVC_FG 
LDLIBS += -lnsl
RPCGENFLAGS = -C -N

# Targets 

all : $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)

$(TARGETS) : $(SOURCES.x) 
    rpcgen $(RPCGENFLAGS) $(SOURCES.x)

$(OBJECTS_CLNT) : $(SOURCES_CLNT.c) $(SOURCES_CLNT.h) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c) 

$(OBJECTS_SVC) : $(SOURCES_SVC.c) $(SOURCES_SVC.h) $(TARGETS_SVC.c) 

$(CLIENT) : $(OBJECTS_CLNT) 
    $(LINK.c) -o $(CLIENT) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(LDLIBS) 

$(SERVER) : $(OBJECTS_SVC) 
    $(LINK.c) -o $(SERVER) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(LDLIBS)

 clean:
     $(RM) core $(TARGETS) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

I'd also like to use multithreading (pthreads) in my final application, which I don't even know if it's possible using this setup. I'd at least have the same problem adding the library path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: obviously, your linker is missing a symbol named `log` - Where's that defined?

Comment: It's supposed to be defined in the `#include <math.h>` path I put in my server code, and called when applying the function. It seems adding paths there is not sufficient since `make` doest not take them into consideration when compiling `.o`files.

Comment: Under Linux and FreeBSD, the mathematical functions (as declared in math.h) are bundled separately in the mathematical library libm. Therefore, if any of those functions are used, the linker must be given the directive `-lm`.

Comment: C functions aren't defined in C header files. They're *declared*
in header files and *defined* in source files (`.c`). To use a
function you need to *link* the object file or library where the
compiled definition resides. You're simply not linking the math
library, `libm`. Recommend study of how C programs are compiled
and linked before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

I just added -lm to the LDLIBS section, worked like a charm.